# How can ı upgrade apache kafka 2.6.0 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

How can I upgrade kafka library slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar and log4j-1.2.17.jar. My kafka version is 2.6.0. I can't upgrade my kafka and zookeeper because there are dependencies with my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, instead of deleting log4j files, kafka needs to be upgraded.I deleted jdbcappander,JMSSink,Chainsaw classes in log4j-1.2.17.jar and I replaced slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar with slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar that has no any vulnerabilities additionally I replaced snappy-java-1.1.10.5.jar with snappy-java-1.1.10.5.jar.

Here delete classes from log4j-1.2.17.jar

jar xvf ../log4j-1.2.17.jar
rm org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class
rm org/apache/log4j/chainsaw
rm org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.class
jar cvf ../log4j-1.2.17-patched.jar .

Replace log4j-1.2.17.jar with the recompiled patched.jar file as above.